# How to efficiently compare items in different lists?

Tags: r, for-loop, control-flow

First off, I am creating a HFT model. I want to execute commands every x amount of seconds. The data I'm currently working with is tick data and has a timestamp indicating new action. I created a time sequence as a list with all the times at the specified intervals.

So I've tried using a double for loop to compare items in the list. As I have been testing this, it had been VERY slow as i run through thousands of lines of code. I am looking for a more efficient way to complete this operation.

I've only used the double for loop to complete this. I have some conditions and other functions within the loop that add up the computing time.

```r
# Demonstration of comparison
time.vec[2] > strptime(as.character(test$Timestamp[1]),format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS") 
> FALSE 
time.vec[3] > strptime(as.character(test$Timestamp[1]),format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS") 
> TRUE

for(i in 2:(nrow(test))){
  for(j in 1:(length(time.vec) - 1)){
    if(time.vec[j] <  strptime(as.character(test$Timestamp[i]),format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS") 
       && time.vec[j + 1] >  strptime(as.character(test$Timestamp[i]), format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%OS")){ # Execute trade
```

Is there a simple way to either make this more efficient, or just a different method of approaching this?

I'm looking for other ways to approach this problem, I don't have much experience with computer science / control flow and only know the basics. So any additional advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use vectorized versions of the comparison functions? eg: ``time.vec < strptime(comparison_time[i])``.

Comment: Great idea! I will try that now.